# Writing simple flash plugin for flowplayer

Tags: actionscript, flash

I'm trying to write a simple plugin for the flash player [flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/) (documentation for writing a plugin for flowplayer can be found [here](http://flowplayer.org/documentation/developer/writing-flash-plugins.html)). I'm new to flash and I think I'm having a problem connecting the .fla file to the .as file when compiling into a .swf. As it is, when I include the plugin, the player doesn't show up.

I've set the .fla's document class to the .as file and added the .as file to the .fla's publishing classpath.

The .as file can be found [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6114719/my_plugin/obfus_plugin.as) and the .fla file can be found [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6114719/my_plugin/obfus_plugin.fla)

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved. Error with classpath